# InAppPurchase in Sandbox(via test user)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

To test InAppPurchase in sandbox, do i need to upload a app in Appstore?
If not then how the code will relate to the dummy app i made in iTunesConnect for inAppPurchase?

Comment: you don't need to upload your application to the Appstore, you can test the InAppPurchase in your real device with the test (or real) account as well but it won't work on the simulator. have you set the `ProductID`s properly? if you have, you can purchase those `ProductID`s in your application.

Comment: I have added NSSet * _productIdentifiers; in .h file .

Comment: I am not sure about how ProductId of InAppPurchase which we added in iTunesConnect will connect to the one which we added in .h file using variable.

Comment: you should add all of the `ProductID`s on the **[itunsconnect.apple.com](http://itunsconnect.apple.com)** website, choose the exists application (or create a new one) and at the right side you will see the _Managing the In-App-Purchase_ button. here you can set all of the `ProductID`s, their types, their prices etc... and then you can use those `ProductID`s in you application. after you've set the `ProductID`s on the iTunesConnect site they are alive `ProductID`s already, it means, with every iTunes account it will work and the real money will be transferred from your real account.

Comment: thanks for details. But i already did that and now i want to know how do i use that product ID in my code? (and how code will know about that product ID's)

Comment: start here i.e. **[Store Kit Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKit_Collection/_index.html)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to upload binary also. Just make sure that status of InAppPurchase item must be "Ready to submit" n not "Submit for review"(for sandbox testing only.) And xcode project will relate to that dummy app via Bundle ID.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @stack , InAppPurchase can not be tested on Simulator. You have to use device to test it. And also, you do not need to submit application for AppStore release.

Please have look at this [blog](http://nixsolutions.com/blog/development/iphone/in-app-purchase-tutorial/) and visit the last section called **Creating the Purchase Product and Test User in iTunes Connect**.

Please let me know if this post is useful for you.

Comment: do we need our own server for sandbox testing?

Comment: We do not require our own server for InAppPurchase testing.

Comment: i have did everything correctly but now am not getting reference for my InAppPurchase itms via method. - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    
    self.products = response.products;
    NSLog(@"response array count=%d",[response.products count]);
    self.request = nil;        
}
So, do i need to add Binary upload to my project? IS it compulsory for InAppPurchase testing also?

Comment: here i always get response.products count=0; ,Though i have two items added in ManageInAppPurchase with the same bundleID as in project.

Comment: yes, that is compulsory for InAppPurchase feature. you need to create sandbox testing user account to test in-app feature.

Comment: i have created test user accound but do i need to add Binary upload also?

Comment: Yes, you need to upload binary to iTunes portal but should not submit it for approval.

Comment: What about this link provided by apple http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html in which they said Q.Must I upload a binary to test In-App Purchase?
No. Testing In-App Purchase does not require uploading a binary.(Frequently Asked Questions 4 section)

Comment: Anyways, everything working in simulator, means atleast, i am able to get the count for my InAppPurchase item in simulater but not in phone. Can you please guide me through that?